# JADE Agent Integration with WSIG

Tags: java, web-services, agent, agents-jade

installed all neccesary pre-requisite for integrating web service with jade. when trying to test out the wsig jade-addon with ant in command prompt like this

`>ant deploy-examples`

it loads up and shows 100 errors , tried different things(The Logger Keeps Popping As Error). Please need serious help as it is a huge project for me.Thanks

Here is the console error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\THEOPHY>cd C:\jade\add-ons\wsig

C:\jade\add-ons\wsig>ant deploy-examples
Buildfile: C:\jade\add-ons\wsig\build.xml

init:
     [echo] JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
     [echo] CATALINA_HOME C:\juddi
     [echo] source dir C:\jade\add-ons\wsig\src
     [echo] build dir C:\jade\add-ons\wsig\webModule\WEB-INF\classes
     [echo] OS platform is Windows 8

SubWCRev:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 46 source files to C:\jade\add-ons\wsig\webModule\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] C:\jade\add-ons\wsig\src\com\tilab\wsig\WSIGConfiguration.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private static Logger logger = Logger.getMyLogger(WSIGConfiguration.class.getName());
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getMyLogger(String)
    [javac]   location: class Logger
    [javac] C:\jade\add-ons\wsig\src\com\tilab\wsig\WSIGConfiguration.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static final String KEY_WSIG_PRESERVE_JAVA_TYPE = SLCodec.PRESERVE_JAVA_TYPES;
    [javac]                                                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable PRESERVE_JAVA_TYPES
    [javac]   location: class SLCodec
    [javac] C:\jade\add-ons\wsig\src\com\tilab\wsig\WSIGConfiguration.java:184: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             return getProperty(jade.core.Profile.LOCAL_PORT);
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable LOCAL_PORT
    [javac]   location: class Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with what version of java it is attempting to target. As you can see there are some warnings that indicate source and target are obsolete. What I had to do to get this working is simply delete the references to the source and target in the build.xml to force it to use a default value.

For example change:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init,SubWCRev" description="Compile WSIG sources">
        <javac  srcdir="${wsigSrc.dir}" 
                debug="${debug-build}"
                destdir="${wsigBuild.dir}" 
                encoding="ISO-8859-1"
                optimize="${optimised-build}"
                includeAntRuntime="no"
                target="1.5"
                source="1.5">
            <classpath refid="wsigCompile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
        <echo>Compilation complete</echo>
    </target>
```

to this:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init,SubWCRev" description="Compile WSIG sources">
        <javac  srcdir="${wsigSrc.dir}" 
                debug="${debug-build}"
                destdir="${wsigBuild.dir}" 
                encoding="ISO-8859-1"
                optimize="${optimised-build}"
                includeAntRuntime="no">
            <classpath refid="wsigCompile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
        <echo>Compilation complete</echo>
    </target>
```